# extract 9 digit number from a string

Tags: php, regex

I basically have an array in php which contains a string, I basically need to filter the string in order to get a 9 digit ID number (which is surrounded by brackets), im sure there could be a way to do this with regex but im clueless.

I know that regex returns its results as an array as there could be multiple results but I know that there will not be multiple results for each string and therefore I need to put the result straight in to my already existing array if possible

**example:**

```
function getTasks(){
   //filter string before inserting into array
   $str['task'] = "meeting mike (298124190)";

   return $str;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by using `preg_replace` you just have one line filter....

```
 $str['task'] = preg_replace('/.*\((\d{9})\).*/', '$1', "meeting mike (298124190)");
```

using `preg_match`

```
$strings = array("meeting mike (298124190)", "meeting mike (298124190)", "meeting mike (298124190)");
foreach ($strings as $string) {
    if (preg_match("|\(([\d]{9})\)|", $string, $matches)) {
        $str[] = $matches[1];
        // OR $str['task'][] = $matches[1];
    }
}
print_r($str);
```

Comment: I just mean extract... I want to extract a 9 digit number from a string. anyway I will give this a try

Comment: this would almost work except that you haven't taken into consideration that there could be other numbers, the ID number is the only number surrounded by brackets

Comment: I've tested this and it works great if there is an ID, but do you have any idea what I can do if there is no ID?

Comment: I think I'll just return 0 but don't worry about it I'll do an if-and-else statement to sort that mess out, thanks anyway

Comment: @ mk_89: there is no reason to do the check twice, just use preg_match.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $str = "meeting mike (298124190)";
    preg_match("/([0-9]{9})/s", $str, $result);

    print_r($result); // $result is an array with the extracted numbers
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming it is the only one (9 digit number surrounded by brackets) the following will do:

```
preg_match("|\(([0-9]{9})\)|", $str['task'], $matches);
return $matches[1]; //Will contain your ID.
```

Answer (score 1):

its somthing like :

```
$str = "meeting mike (298124190)";
$pattern = '/[0-9]{9}/';
if (preg_match($pattern, $str, $matches))
{

    echo $matches[0];
}
```